# Output HTML depending on the current time of user

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to do the following:

if time is between 7am-12pm (mon-sat) then output html code else output something else.

I currently have tried: (ignore the time in the code, this was just for testing purposes - I still want it to do be done for 7am-12pm)

```
<script>
            var today = new Date()
var curHr = today.getHours()

if (curHr < 12) {
  phoneText .innerHTML="<div class='col-sm-6 col-md-3'><div class='support-box'><div class='icon green'><i class='fas fa-comments'></i></div><div class='details-holder'><div class='title'>Live Chat</div><a href='javascript:$zopim.livechat.window.show();' style='color:white;'>Start a live chat</a></div></div>";
} else if (curHr < 18) {
  phoneText .innerHTML="<div class='col-sm-6 col-md-3'><div class='support-box'><div class='icon green'><i class='fas fa-comments'></i></div><div class='details-holder'><div class='title'>Live Chat</div><a href='javascript:$zopim.livechat.window.show();' style='color:white;'>Start a live chat</a></div></div>";
} else {
  phoneText .innerHTML="<div class='col-sm-6 col-md-3'><div class='support-box'><div class='icon green'><i class='fas fa-comments'></i></div><div class='details-holder'><div class='title'>Live Chat</div><a href='javascript:$zopim.livechat.window.show();' style='color:white;'>Start a live chat</a></div></div>";
}</script>
```

I then have `<div id="phone"></div>`

Comment: Please provide more information. What is `phoneText`? is it an element?

Comment: I saw a thread somewhere that allowed that to work.

Comment: If that does not work, how can I output those innerHTML into the div with id"phone"?

Comment: What is happening when you run that? are you getting an error? is something not appearing?

Comment: Nothing appears, nothing happens.

Comment: can you post the code somewhere?

Comment: This uses class's and jQuery, this isn't included to your code.

Comment: "*[If] time is between 7am-12pm (mon-sat) then output html code"* - what HTML code? "*...else output something else.*" - what, exactly, is 'something else' that you want to output? Output it where? All the HTML in each of the cases you've shown seems to be the same; so what do you expect? What's your [MCVE] code that allows us to see what you're working with, and trying? What problems are you experiencing? What help do you want?

Answer (score 0):

In your if you should create a var for the target in html `var outpout = document.getElementById("phone")` and use it to `outpout.innerHTML`. But you can't insert here an entire div. So you could create all the div in your html for each of the cases and put them in `display : none` to hide them in your CSS. Then you take them in js like `var divOne = document.getElementById = "div_hour_first_case"` and then `divOne.style.display = "flex"` in your if to show the expected div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://jsfiddle.net/opecmshb/2/

I used `curHr = 11` for example because in my jsfiddle `var curHr = today.getHours()` didn't work